# How to code this generic type C# snippet?

Tags: c#, generics

Simplified repeated code for each entity type is

```
public IList<entity1> GetEntity1(.. query params ..)
{
    IQueryable<entity1> query = context.entity1;

    query = from refDataType in query
            where refDataType.Id > 0
            select refDataType;
    .
    . plus more changes to query same for each entity
    .

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I wanted to create a generic function that creates the query, but not sure how to go about it?

ie in the following snippet, How do I code for ReturnAGenericQuery?

```
 public IList<entity1> GetEntity1(.. query params ..)
{
    IQueryable<entity1> query = context.entity1;    
    query = ReturnAGenericQuery of type entity1
    return query.ToList();
}

public IList<entity2> GetEntity2(.. query params ..)
{
    IQueryable<entity2> query = context.entity2;    
    query = ReturnAGenericQuery of type entity2
    return query.ToList();
}

private IQueryable<T> ReturnAGenericQuery<T> ()
{
    return IQueryable of entity1 or entity2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is a little vague, but it looks like you need something along the lines of:

```
private IQueryable<T> ReturnAGenericQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> source)
    where T : SomeBaseTypeForAllYourEntities
{
    IQueryable<T> result =
        from refDataType in source
        where refDataType.Id > 0
        select refDataType;

    // Other stuff here

    return result;
}

public IList<Entity1> GetEntity1( ... )
{
    return ReturnAGenericQuery(context.entity1).ToList();
}
```

The reason you need the '`where T :`' clause is because T needs to be a type that has a property '`Id`' for your LINQ where-clause to work ... so you'd need to derive Entity1 and Entity2 from a base class that defines that property. If you need any other properties for the 'other stuff' these will need to be added to the base class too.

**Addendum:**
If `context.entity1` (whatever collection that refers to) is not an `IQueryable<entity1>`, then you may need to use `context.entity1.AsQueryable()` instead.

Originally my query was wrong, it was supposed to query `from refDataType in source` rather than `in result`... duh.

Provided you have the right kind of inheritance structure (see below), this compiles fine.

```
public class SomeBaseTypeForAllYourEntities
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

sealed public class Entity1 : SomeBaseTypeForAllYourEntities
{
    ... other properties, etc. ...
}
```

Comment: This won't compile (even if you give 'source' and 'query' the same name) until you give the method a 2nd type parameter.  'result' is IQueryable<typeof(refDataType)> which is not the same as the entity type T.

Comment: There was an 'AsQueryable()' missing, and there was a typo in my query, but other than that this compiles just fine... added some more detail to be absolutely clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need an interface.

```
private IQueryable<T, R> ReturnAGenericQuery<T> (T entity) where T : IQueryable, IHasRefDataType
{
    return from DataType refDataType in entity
           where refDataType.Id > 0
           select refDataType;
}

struct DataType
{
    public int Id;
}

public interface IHasRefDataType
{
    DataType refDataType;
}
```

Comment: @Robert: No, that'd be IHazRefDataType, surely?